# Tabla HTML con encabezados fijos responsivos

Tags: html5, css3, responsive

Quiero hacer que mis tablas HTML tengan un encabezado fijo, pero que estos a su vez sean responsivos. He logrado hacer que los encabezados sean fijos, pero no se adaptan a otros tamaños de pantalla porque estoy usando pixeles como unidades de medida, pero la verdad no he encontrado de que otra manera hacerlo, por eso pido que me ayuden.

Gracias!!!

Comment: La mejor manera de mantener proporción como la que tú necesitas es usando porcentajes en lugar de pixeles. De esta manera cada vez que se ajuste el canvas el porcentaje mantendrá relación.

Comment: Entiendo, hare lo que me dices y luego te comento si me funcionó. Gracias.

Comment: Me funciona pero ahora el problema que tengo es cuando aparece la barra desplazadora, ya que me desalinea el encabezado con las celdas del tbody. He intentado ver como hacer que la barra salga hacia afuera y no empuje las celdas del tbody pero no encuentro la solución.